# scikit-learn, getting weird result with SVR regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

I'm really new to machine learning and I'm having problems getting results from my dataset by using SVR algoritm. My data consists of 1800 observations and I have 66 features to predict those observations. My code with short descriptions  looks as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVR
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler  

y = df['Col1']
X = df[['Col2','Col4','Col8','Col9' etc]]

# STANDARDIZE AND DIVIDE INTO TRAIN AND TEST DATA

scaler = StandardScaler()
X = scaler.fit_transform(X)
y = scaler.fit_transform(y)

from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.3,random_state=1)

# FIND BEST PARAMETERS

C_range = 10.0 ** np.arange(-4, 4)
gamma_range = 10.0 ** np.arange(-4, 4)
param_grid = dict(gamma=gamma_range.tolist(), C=C_range.tolist())
svr = GridSearchCV(SVR(kernel='rbf', gamma=0.1),param_grid, cv=10)
svr.fit(X_train,y_train)

print(svr.best_score_)
print(svr.best_estimator_)

# FIT THE MODEL USING BEST ESTIMATOR

model = SVR(C=10.0, cache_size=200, coef0=0.0, degree=3, epsilon=0.1, gamma=100.0,
  kernel='rbf', max_iter=-1, shrinking=True, tol=0.001, verbose=False)

model.fit(X_train,y_train)
results = model.predict(X_test)
```

After running this code my model predicts the same result for every observation in the testing dataset.

```
In: results
Out: array([ 0.02213646,  0.02213646,  0.02213646,  0.02213646,  0.02213646,
        0.02213646,  0.02213646,  0.02213646,  0.02213646,  0.02213646 etc
```

Did I miss something in the code?

It seems that the problem is in the data i'm trying to predict, since the code works fine with different database/random X and y. I wonder if there is any particular reason why ML algorithm might predict nearly the same outcome for every observation in test dataset, when the real outcomes differ substantially.

Comment: I did not understand why are your doing y = scaler.fit_transform(y). Normally in scikit, you do not fit_transform y. Any particular reason why you are doing so? Please check.

Comment: Tried you same code with y = np.array([1,2,1,2,1,1,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,2,1,1,2]) \n X = np.array([[1,0,1,1,1,0],[1,1,0,0,0,0],[1,0,1,1,0,1],[1,1,0,1,1,0],[1,0,1,1,1,1],[1,1,0,0,0,0],[1,0,1,1,0,1],[1,1,0,0,0,0],[1,0,1,1,1,0],[1,1,0,1,1,0],
[1,0,1,1,1,0],[1,1,0,0,0,0],[1,0,1,1,0,1],[1,1,0,1,1,0],[1,0,1,1,1,1],[1,1,0,0,0,0],[1,0,1,1,0,1],[1,1,0,0,0,0],[1,0,1,1,1,0],[1,1,0,1,1,0]]) \n I got results output as \n 
[ 1.12534423 -0.71589722 -0.71589722 -0.71679626 -0.71589722 -0.71679626]

Comment: I think you are getting the correct output, just loop/parse through results, and print, or else output it to a file, and then compare.

Comment: Well, leaving 'y' as it is does not change the result, the model still predicts the same number for every observation in the testing dataset. I'm also not sure whether I need to fit_transform 'y' for this particular problem. My initial thought that it is usually good to fit_transform(y) for regression type machine learning problems, since it takes some weight away from extreme 'y' values. Might be wrong here...

Comment: For debugginmg purposes, try to do the same first with a low dimensional data set, say three feature dimenisons, where it is easy to you to see whether yor code works.